# Python - Can I sort a dictionary by one of the values that is in a list?

Tags: python, dictionary

How can I have the following dictionary sorted based on a value that is in a list?

```
Data = {1:["name",2010],2:["name",2005],3:["name",2000]}
sortedDataByYear = {3:["name",2000],2:["name",2005],1:["name",2010]}
```

I have tried sorted(lambda), but there is something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Dictionaries can't be sorted.
However, you can do this:

```
Data = {1:["name",2010],2:["name",2005],3:["name",2000]}
sorted(Data.items(), key = lambda x: x[1])
```

This will return a list instead, but sorted on the first index in ascending order.

Comment: actually, they can, since python 3.6 IIRC

Comment: You can apply dict to your result to create a dictionary as desired and also use x[1][1] to sort on the year rather than the list, so the answer becomes `dict(sorted(Data.items(), key = lambda x: x[1][1]))`